# IIS traffic between 2 websites

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

Two simple IIS10 sites: `foo` is a static front end website. `bar` serves up dynamic ASP.NET applications; all external domain traffic routes to foo. `foo`'s nav bar either displays foo pages, or routes the request to bar, which displays an interactive application in a new tab. On completion the user kills the tab and control reverts to foo. Both websites are published independently.

`foo1` and `bar1` are the IIS sites; they have only default application and virtual directories. `foo1` is bound to my domain name to get all internet traffic; `bar1` is bound to `foo` to get only redirects. To dispatch a call to bar, foo sends a URL `http://bar1/thisapp.aspx`

In use, enter the domain name into any browser and it directs to `foo` perfectly. In development all routing to `bar` works perfectly but when tested on the internet, the URL to bar results in "web page not found". If I change the redirect to http://ibm.com it works immediately.

Research into IIS suggests that multiple website support is what it is supposed to do, but I find the complexity of sites, application pools, virtual domains and on and on bewilderingly frustrating, and there are NO straightforward examples to follow. It seems my redirect is wrong but as it works in testing I don't know what the problem is.

Please can someone suggest why my redirects do not work.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Your arrangement seems overly complex - and it's hard to understand your problem. Is there a reason you don't have a single self-contained web-application that does everything? Can you post a screenshot of your IIS Administration tool? What do you mean by "bound to foo to get only redirects"? Also please don't use names like "foo" and "bar" to describe both websites and domain names, and I'm unsure how "foo" is different from "foo1".

Comment: There is something missing in your story.  If foo is a static web site, how does it issue redirects?  Do you mean that foo *links* to bar?  Is bar accessible on the internet or not?  Is foo acting as a *proxy*? A redirect requires internet access to the target of the redirect.  A redirect does not utilize any sort of communication directly between sites, it all goes through the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The original bar ASP.NET website was integrated but the UI was criticized for being unfriendly so I created foo in a newer tool. I used foo for the website and foo1 as the name of the IIS site that

Comment: Sorry, hit Enter! foo URLs are my issue. ASP.NET website bar was integrated but the UI was inadequate so I built foo in a new tool. foo and bar are production folder. 
foo1, bar1 are IIS sites with physical paths foo and bar. 
foo1 is bound to a host bearing the domain name. bar1 is bound to a host named foo1. domain traffic goes to foo and foo1 traffic to bar. 
foo buttons issue URLs. foo1 pages are fine; http://bar/barpage.aspx works perfectly in local testing but 404s when accessed over the internet. What alternative can I use? Should I create a domain for bar?
Will reconstruct IIS.

Comment: Dai and John I have reconstructed the IIS and have a diagram but don't see how to share it; if you can contact my email I will be glad to forward it.